# Failed to register task definition in ECS with GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

I am setting up a Github Actions CI to AWS Fargate.
But facing a permission issue on the step of Deploy Amazon ECS task definition.

Getting the following error:

**##[error]Failed to register task definition in ECS: Fargate requires task definition to have execution role ARN to support ECR images.**

Already verified the following:

- ecsTaskExecutionRole exists
- AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy exists
- AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy is attached to the role
- Trust policy is in place
- Task Definition is assigned to the ecsTaskExecutionRole  Role
  all outlined in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html

Any hints on how to further debug / resolve things are appreciated

```
 Deploy Amazon ECS task definition2s
    cluster: default
##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Deploy Amazon ECS task definition'
##[debug]Evaluating: success()
##[debug]Evaluating success:
##[debug]=> true
##[debug]Result: true
##[debug]Starting: Deploy Amazon ECS task definition
##[debug]Loading inputs
##[debug]Evaluating: steps.task-def.outputs.task-definition
##[debug]Evaluating Index:
##[debug]..Evaluating Index:
##[debug]....Evaluating Index:
##[debug]......Evaluating steps:
##[debug]......=> Object
##[debug]......Evaluating String:
##[debug]......=> 'task-def'
##[debug]....=> Object
##[debug]....Evaluating String:
##[debug]....=> 'outputs'
##[debug]..=> Object
##[debug]..Evaluating String:
##[debug]..=> 'task-definition'
##[debug]=> '/home/runner/work/_temp/task-definition--3322-yHLvp6V1t9QO-.json'
##[debug]Result: '/home/runner/work/_temp/task-definition--3322-yHLvp6V1t9QO-.json'
##[debug]Loading env
Run aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition@v1
##[debug]Registering the task definition
##[error]Failed to register task definition in ECS: Fargate requires task definition to have execution role ARN to support ECR images.
```

Answer (score 3):

Issue found, I had not correctly updated the task definition json to declare the correct ARN

Comment: Can you include an example of your task definition? I've got a similar problem.

Comment: @Zakes Try just adding a line `"executionRoleArn": "ecsTaskExecutionRole"` in your task definition JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new `TaskExecutionRole` and include the `ARN` in it.

For example,

```
{
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "nginx",
      "image": "nginx:latest",
      "memory": 256,
      "cpu": 256,
      "essential": true,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 80,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        }
      ],
      "logConfiguration":{
            "logDriver":"awslogs",
            "options":{
               "awslogs-group":"awslogs-nginx-ecs",
               "awslogs-region":"us-east-1",
               "awslogs-stream-prefix":"ecs"
            }
      }
    }
  ],
  "volumes": [],
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "family": "nginx",
  "memory": "512",
  "cpu": "256",
  "executionRoleArn": "ARN"
}
```

New Role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "CWLogGroupManagement",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                "logs:PutRetentionPolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

To the created role, add this policy. After the role has been formed, copy the ARN file and attach it to the previously mentioned task-definition json file.