# Authorization Error in Deploy AWS ECS Task Definition via Github Actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, github-actions, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

I am trying to Deploy my image present in ECR using AWS ECS Fargate via Github Actions. It is a Github private repository as well as a private ECR repository. The AWS secrets are properly configured. I have also created an `ecsTaskExecutionRole` and included it in the Task Definition as per the AWS docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html#task-execution-private-auth). But the following error persists:

```
Error: Failed to register task definition in ECS: User: arn:aws:iam::***:user/service-account-ecr-push is not authorized to perform: ecs:RegisterTaskDefinition on resource: *
Error: User: arn:aws:iam::***:user/service-account-ecr-push is not authorized to perform: ecs:RegisterTaskDefinition on resource: *
```

The Github Actions YAML file

```
# Workflow triggered when there is a new Release on GitHub
name: Release a new image on ECR

on:
  # Trigger the workflow on push or pull request,
  # but only for the main branch
  push:
    branches:
      - actions

jobs:
  main:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: "us-east-1"

      - name: Login to Amazon ECR
        id: login-ecr
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

      - name: Get the version
        id: get_version
        run: echo ::set-output name=VERSION::${GITHUB_REF#refs/tags/}

      - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
        id: build-image
        env:
          ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
          ECR_REPOSITORY: search-website
          IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
        run: |
          docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG -f docker/Dockerfile .
          docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
          echo "::set-output name=image::$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG"

      - name: Fill in the new image ID in the Amazon ECS task definition
        id: task-def
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition@v1
        with:
          task-definition: deploy/task.json
          container-name: harsh-test
          image: ${{ steps.build-image.outputs.image }}

      - name: Deploy Amazon ECS task definition
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition@v1
        id: ecs-deploy
        with:
          task-definition: ${{ steps.task-def.outputs.task-definition }}
          service: harsh-test-service
          cluster: harsh-test
          wait-for-service-stability: true
```

The Task Definition JSON

```
{
  "ipcMode": null,
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::387352008451:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "environmentFiles": null,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "secretOptions": null,
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/first-run-task-definition",
          "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      },
      "entryPoint": [],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "command": [],
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 512,
      "environment": [],
      "resourceRequirements": null,
      "ulimits": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "secrets": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memory": null,
      "memoryReservation": 1024,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "stopTimeout": null,
      "image": "387352008451.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/search-website:v0.1.0",
      "startTimeout": null,
      "firelensConfiguration": null,
      "dependsOn": null,
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": true,
      "links": [],
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "pseudoTerminal": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "harsh-test"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": "1024",
  "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::387352008451:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "compatibilities": [
    "EC2",
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:387352008451:task-definition/first-run-task-definition:4",
  "family": "first-run-task-definition",
  "requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.21"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
    }
  ],
  "pidMode": null,
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "cpu": "512",
  "revision": 4,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "inferenceAccelerators": null,
  "proxyConfiguration": null,
  "volumes": []
}
```

Comment: There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63673643/failed-to-register-task-definition-in-ecs-with-github-actions). But it doesn't help as the issue in that case was that a wrong Task definition was uploaded. But here, the task definition is correct as it has been obtained from AWS web console from a Task definition that works well on console, but fails on github actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved by adding the `AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role` policy to the `ecsInstanceRole` role as per the AWS docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/instance_IAM_role.html)

Answer (score 3):

There is a missing permission for the user user/service-account-ecr-push:

```
User: arn:aws:iam::***:user/service-account-ecr-push 
is not authorized to perform: ecs:RegisterTaskDefinition
on resource: *
```

It's not related to the role. It's the IAM user permissions that are not correct. The user needs the `ecs:RegisterTaskDefinition` in order to do the operation.

Try adding the following permission to the above user:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ecs:RegisterTaskDefinition",
        "ecs:ListTaskDefinitions",
        "ecs:DescribeTaskDefinition"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

For more information on this policy see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/security_iam_id-based-policy-examples.html#IAM_task_definition_policies

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In my case, the issue got resolved by adding the `AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role` policy to the `ecsInstanceRole` role as per the AWS docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/instance_IAM_role.html)